# TypeScript Error: Ts 8006, Ts 8010 when build React Native App?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.

[Click "image description" here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwkSW.png)

Comment: From the image, the App.js is a JS file instead of TS file. which one do you want to use? If you are using ts, please change the file to App.ts